# Finding numbers that satisfy $AB-BA = 54$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

> Let's suppose that $AB, BA$ are two-digit numbers. How many different
> numbers $AB$ exist that satisfy $AB-BA = 54$?

If we write $AB = 10a + b$ and $BA = 10b+a$, then

$$AB-BA = 54\equiv (10a + b)-(10b+a) = 9(a+b)= 54\equiv a+b = 6$$

Where $a, b\in \{1,\cdots, 9\}$. Then $AB = 24, 42, 15, 51, 33$ are the whole distinct solutions.

**EDIT:** I lacked the sufficient attention to work with correct sign of $b$:

$$9(a-b)= 54\equiv a-b = 6$$

Where $a, b\in \{1,\cdots, 9\}$.Then, the correct solutions are: $AB = 71, 82, 93$.

Comment: Watch your signs.  Also, had there not been a sign error you should have been able at this point to make a final conclusion that confirms or denies the existence of answers to the original question.  If $AB=24$ is it true that $AB-BA=54$?  Or if $AB=51$ is $AB-BA=54$?  You should always take the time to check if your answers are actually answers at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, with a simple mistake in the signs, the whole solution has gone wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good attempt.

$$(10a+b)-(10b+a)=9a-9b=9(a-b)=54$$

$$a-b=6$$

Can you complete it?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I had the wrong sign in front of $b$ :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote the two-digit numbers as $AB$ and $BA$, where $A$ and $B$ are digits. The value of $AB$ is $10A + B$, and the value of $BA$ is $10B + A$.

The given condition is $AB - BA = 54$. Substituting the expressions for $AB$ and $BA$, we get:

$10A + B - (10B + A) = 54$

Simplifying the equation:

$10A + B - 10B - A = 54$

Combining like terms:

$9A - 9B = 54$

Dividing both sides by $9$:

$A - B = 6$

Now, we need to find all possible pairs of digits $A$ and $B$ such that $A - B = 6$. Since $A$ and $B$ are digits, they must be between $0$ and $9$ (inclusive).

The pairs that satisfy $A - B = 6$ are:

$(A, B) = (6, 0), (7, 1), (8, 2), (9, 3)$

For each pair, the corresponding two-digit numbers $AB$ and $BA$ are:

$$(A, B) = (6, 0) \implies AB = 60, BA = \text{invalid}$$
$$(A, B) = (7, 1) \implies AB = 71, BA = 17$$
$$(A, B) = (8, 2) \implies AB = 82, BA = 28$$
$$(A, B) = (9, 3) \implies AB = 93, BA = 39$$

So, there are four different two-digit numbers $AB$ that satisfy the given condition.

Comment: By assumption, $AB$ and $BA$ are both two-digit numbers, so $BA = 06$ won't count as a valid one for this problem.

Comment: @Keane I appreciate your clarification. I have edited.

Comment: No worries at all.